# Rigify on a Frankenstein Rig Not Working

Tags: rigging, rigify

[image: Frankenstein rig issue]

**[Previous Question; I would still like advice please]**
I made a humanoid mesh but it's body doesn't line up (at all) with the basic humanoid rig found in Rigify. Instead of using Rigify I built the bone structure myself and then used that for animations, but Rigify seems like a better option.

Unfortunately when I went into Object Data Properties and clicked 'metarig' I received errors such as [spine004]. After looking up that issue it seemed my rig is just too different to use with Rigify. I selected each bone and tried to assign it a rig individually and still couldn't access the the loopy lines that surround the mesh that means it worked. So I tried to go into the Object Data Properties and clicked 'metarig' one more time. This time I didn't receive an error.

But also seems like... Nothing happened. Did it work? How do I access that cool loopy-line thing that animators use to make fighting poses?

**[Update]**
I tried the advice given, which was to align the standard rig to the model and then attach it with the intention of deleting unnecessary bones afterwards. But when I pressed 'Generate Rig' under the *Rigify* button only a tiny green copy of the face bones was present at the bottom of the mesh. Why did this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: I've had this problem recently. If you want to use rigify you can't really add bones or change their names. Just move things around until they fit, rigify it, then add anything else you need on top.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/index.html#rigify) on how to use rigify? It is very thorough, I recommend taking the time to read it. You will have to reposition the bones to fit your humanoid...

Comment: Thank you both for the help! I admit I haven't fully read through the documentation, but I am going to try using a base metarig and then attaching it to my mesh first, then deleting unneeded bones.